# upload multiple images using volley multipart android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I wrote some code in android to upload a single bitmap to my server, now I'm trying to upload multiple images to my server, but only the last selected image gets uploaded

Below is how I get the bitmap image in my **onActivityResult**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
            int currentItem = 0;
            while (currentItem < count) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();
                currentItem = currentItem + 1;
                try {
                    arrayList.add(imageUri);
                    images.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), imageUri));  // Code to handle multiple images
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "File select error", e);
                }
            }

        } else if (data.getData() != null) {

            final Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
                mCoverImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File select error", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code used to upload a single picture to the server

```
    public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

@Override
        protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();

            long imageName = System.currentTimeMillis();
            params.put("featured_image", new DataPart(imageName + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));

            return params;
        }
```

The above code works fine

And below is the code used to upload multiple images to the server

```
public byte[] getFileArrayDataFromDrawable(Bitmap[] bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.length; i++) {
        bitmap[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

 @Override
        protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            Bitmap stockArr[] = new Bitmap[images.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                stockArr[i] = images.get(i;
            }

            long imageName2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            params.put("other_images[]", new DataPart(imageName2 + ".png", getFileArrayDataFromDrawable(stockArr)));
            
            return params;
        }
```

But only the last selected image gets uploaded.
What am I doing wrong? and how can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by iterating over the images in a for loop and adding the other_images[i] param in each for loop that executes

```
 for (i in images.indices) {
     stockArr[i] = images[i]

     try {
         val imageName2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
         params["other_images[$i]"] = DataPart("$imageName2.png", getFileDataFromDrawable(stockArr[i]!!))
     } catch (e: Exception) {
         e.printStackTrace()
     }
 }

 return params
```

Answer (score 1):

`compress` only save last bitmap to `byteArrayOutputStream` try this code

```
    @Override
    protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() {
        Map<String, List<VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart>> params = new HashMap<>();
        Bitmap stockArr[] = new Bitmap[images.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            stockArr[i] = images.get(i);
        }

        ArrayList<VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> parts = new ArrayList<VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart>();
        for (Bitmap bitmap : stockArr) {
            long imageName2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            parts.add(new DataPart(imageName2 + ".png", getFileArrayDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));
        }
        params.put("other_images[]", parts);

        return params;
    }
```

```
    public byte[] getFileArrayDataFromDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: i had to make some modifications, but i ran into more problems, the method cannot return imagesByteList  as List<Byte> it needs to return Byte[]

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221698/room-for-kennedy-and-cong-hi?highlights=false

Comment: Edited, check it

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the byte array errors that popped up earlier, but for some reason, only the first selected image still gets uploaded

Comment: Really, did you double check with server side to encode byte array contains one or more images?

Comment: yes on server side I upload images as files via postman, and that works

Comment: parts cant be added to params since params is not an arraylist, i'd do some debugging and try and figure it out. i think i would have to modify my volley class

Answer (score 0):

call the getBytes method like

there is no need to create Arraylist to collect bitmaps.

`ArrayList<Bitmap> images;` // create array to collect images also init in oncreateview method.

`images.add(bitmap)` // add images as many you want in onActivityResult

other part of this request visit to [upload multiple images](https://github.com/Ankit7791/Android-Volley-Multipart-Request/blob/master/VolleyMultipartRequest.java) this is for single image upload and implement the code blow for multiple

```
@Override
protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() {
    Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {

            long imageName2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            params.put("images["+i+"]", new DataPart(imageName2 + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawableData(images.get(i))));
    }
    return params;
}
```

```
public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawableData(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getByteCount());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            bitmap.recycle();
            return byteArray;
        }
```